# Explanation of Cramer-Wold theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-theory

I was trying to understand mathematically what the statement of Cramer-Wold theorem means.

Intuitively, I was told that two probability distribution $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent if all their one dimensional projections on any direction of the unit ball are equal.

I was trying to parse this statement into equations and quantifiers and wanted to check what it meant rigorously. Does it mean that if we have two distributions represented as normalized vector $P \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and we compute a projection for all/any unit vector chosen at random from the unit sphere, say $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then their inner products are the same? i.e. if:

$$ \langle P, t \rangle \text{ and }  \langle Q, t \rangle $$

are the inner products, then $\langle P, t \rangle = \langle Q, t \rangle$ if and only if (iff) $P = Q$ (i.e. are the same vector)? Is that what the Crammer-Wold theorem meant or am I misunderstanding it?

---

As a reference, I did try reading the wikipedia article on this but couldn't understand what it was saying or how it was connected my above interpretation. Clarifications on that, specially specifying how it connects it to my above interpretation are welcome!

Comment: It appears Cramer-Wold theorem is related to convergence to a distribution, not comparing two distribution.

Comment: @Creator you are right. However, one could create an equivalence class where two distributions are considered equal iff they converge to the same distribution. I think thats what they meant by equivalent. Thats probably why they did not say equals (since that would be technically wrong).